# How to read true/false response from server-side script to return true/false to a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery process that I want to run, but only if a response from a PHP script is `true`.

I want to check the output of a few different PHP scripts every 2 seconds, which will determine whether my jQuery process can proceed.

How can that be done?

I get stuck when needing to use the [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function as the resulting data from PHP would be passed to a `success` callback function. I can't figure out how to get my `check_php_script_A_returns_false()` function to return `true` or `false`.

Here's what I have in mind:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#switch').prop('checked', false);

    // Listen event: turn process off/on
    // Every 2 seconds, call is_trigger_met() to see if process can be kicked off.
    var intervalId = null;
    $('#switch').change(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        intervalId = setInterval(is_trigger_met, 2000);
      else
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
}


function is_trigger_met() {
    if ( check_php_script_A_returns_false() )
        return false;

    if ( check_php_script_B_returns_false() )
        return false;

    // ... run my process here ...

    return true;
} 

function check_php_script_A_returns_false() {
    // What do I do here to check php script?
    // Do I use jQuery.ajax() function with async = false? 
    // If so, an the PHP response is TRUE, how do I make that 
    // 'return true/false' for THIS check_php_script_A_returns_false() function?
    return true/false;
}
```

Comment: Use [JSON](http://json.org/) - See: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json-encode), [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: @DaveRandom When `getJSON()` is used, a `success` callback function is called where the resulting JSON can the parsed. My problem is, when I parse that to determine a `true` or `false` result from the PHP, how do I get the "containing" function `check_php_script_A_returns_false()` to return true/false so my script can proceed?

Comment: `echo json_encode(array('result' => $result))` where `$result` is the boolean, and in jQ `success: function(data) { if (data.result) { /*true*/ } else { /*false*/ } }`

Comment: For the record, a `boolean` is a valid JSON type. But, a better design  may be to return an Object that you can easily extend as @DaveRandom suggested. If this is absolutely not needed then the initial idea is fine

Answer (score 0):

From PHP you've to return `TRUE` OR `FALSE` as a string.

And in Javascript you've to match like

```
if( response == 'TRUE' ){
 retrun true;
} else {
 return false;
}
```

Comment: The PHP script **is** returning a `true` / `false` value, is the jQuery side I can't figure out.

Comment: @roasted It's a string, that will always be true unless the server returns no data.

Comment: @DaveRandom  Using '!!' will parse it to boolean type, so your comment is not accurate in this case

Comment: @roasted `var test = 'false'; console.log(!!test); //logs true` - try it, the only string value that JS will cast to `false` is the empty string.